# cv_bridge: boost-python not found (Noetic, Fedora 32)

Tags: ros, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any ideas why this fails and what the workaround is?

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.69.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2166 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'cv_bridge':
  Command '['/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/root/ros_catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cv_bridge', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge && /root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /root/ros_catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cv_bridge -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.



CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.69.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2166 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)
   
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'cv_bridge':
  Command '['/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/root/ros_catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cv_bridge', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge && /root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /root/ros_catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cv_bridge -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.


  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake cmTC_84cd7/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_84cd7.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_84cd7.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_84cd7.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_84cd7.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_84cd7
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_84cd7.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_84cd7.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_84cd7  -lpthreads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_84cd7.dir/build.make:107: cmTC_84cd7] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cv_bridge/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:141: cmTC_84cd7/fast] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360283/cv_bridge:-boost-python-not-found-(noetic,-fedora-32)/) by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2020-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Any ideas why this fails and what the workaround is?

The error message seems rather clear:

> ```
> Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.69.0")
> ```

according to CMake, your Boost installation does not have the `python` module.

So two options:

1. if you're certain it should be present, try to find out why CMake doesn't find it
2. if it's not present, make sure to install it

Looks like [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1793496) documents a similar problem.

---

Edit: from trying this out in a Docker container (`fedora:32`), it would appear the version suffix for Boost Python 1.69 on Fedora 32 needs to be `python3.8`.

So it seems this would need to be changed in [cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/0a908b0bcf33a4374b26b8572860ff48da19f74a/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt), specifically [these lines](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/0a908b0bcf33a4374b26b8572860ff48da19f74a/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt#L6-L18).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-25**:
it's there:

```
locate libboost_python
/usr/lib64/libboost_python38.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_python38.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_python38.so.1.69.0
Package boost-python3-1.69.0-18.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
```

I [found a suggestion](https://github.com/google-research/football/issues/108#issuecomment-661816768) to use `elseif` in the `CMakeList.txt` file, but I'm not sure how to do that and which file that is.

Or [does this suggestion](https://github.com/conan-community/community/issues/171#issuecomment-575038365) to use `BOOST_AUTO_LINK_TAGGED` or `BOOST_AUTO_LINK_VERSIONED` or `BOOST_AUTO_LINK_SYSTEM` apply? Not sure which to choose, unless that's only for Windows.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-25**:
I have no idea right now.

Does a plain `CMakeLists.txt` with something like this also fail?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test CXX)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS python)
```

If it does, this would not be a ROS problem any more, but a plain CMake one.

> Package boost-python3-1.69.0-18.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.

does that also install the development headers? Those are typically needed, not just the runtime library.

---

Edit: [this](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/0a908b0bcf33a4374b26b8572860ff48da19f74a/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt#L6-L18) is the logic used in `cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt`. It could be the conditional there doesn't work on your system.

Perhaps the `python` there should be `python38` or something similar.

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-25**:
I believe the dev headers were already isntalled:

```
Package boost-python3-devel-1.69.0-18.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
```

What folder is the correct `CMakeLists.txt` file that I should be looking for? Is it `~/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt` So just remove all of the contents of that file and replace it with your suggested 3 lines?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-25**:\

> So just remove all of the contents of that file and replace it with your suggested 3 lines?

No.

You create a new empty directoy somewhere (perhaps in `/tmp`), then create a new, empty `CMakeList.txt` and add those lines. Then save. Then `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..`.

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-25**:
What would the full `cmake` command be?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-25**:
That is the full `cmake` command.

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-25**:
*Perhaps the python there should be python38 or something similar.*
I changed in `~/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt`

```
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED python3.8)
  else()
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED python3.8)
```

Now getting a different error:

```
Errors     << controller_interface:cmake /root/ros_catkin_ws/logs/controller_interface/build.cmake.002.log
CMake Warning at /root/ros_catkin_ws/install/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:160 (message):
  skipping gmock 'controller_base_test' in project 'controller_interface'
  because gmock was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /root/ros_catkin_ws/install/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:89 (_catkin_add_executable_with_google_test)
  /root/ros_catkin_ws/install/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:63 (_catkin_add_google_test)
  CMakeLists.txt:33 (catkin_add_gmock)

CMake Error at /root/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_control/controller_interface/CMakeLists.txt:34 (target_link
```

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-25**:
ok

```
That is the full cmake command.
```

Got it thanks see below:

```
cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.69.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2166 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-25**:
Your last two comments are confusing.

Did it or did it not work?

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-25**:
Sorry `Your last two comments are confusing.`

The cmake command from `/tmp` fails with:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.69.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2166 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
```

In the mean time I made a change to `~/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt` and replaced the Python version to 3.8 as noted and now getting a different error when running `catkin_build`:

```
CMake Warning at /root/ros_catkin_ws/install/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:160 (message):
  skipping gmock 'controller_base_test' in project 'controller_interface'
  because gmock was not found
```

But it's there:

```
gtest-devel-1.10.0-1.fc32.x86_64 & gtest-devel-1.10.0
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-25**:
Can't help you with that I'm afraid.

Your original problem was sort-of solved (ie: problems with Python detection), so I suggest you open a new question.

And mark this one as *answered*.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-25**:\

> In the mean time I made a change to `~/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt` and replaced the Python version to 3.8 as noted

it would be good to submit this as a PR to the `cv_bridge` repository. Otherwise the next person trying to build this on Fedora will run into the same problem(s).

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-25**:
[@gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) is correct `~/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt` needs to reference Python 3.8. I believe my previous attempts were failing as the original line had:

```
 if(PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING VERSION_LESS "3.8")
```

I changed it to the following and even modified the last line in case the version string check failed so it'd always find `python3.8`:

```
  if(PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING VERSION_LESS "3.9")
    # Debian Buster
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED python3.8)
  else()
    # Ubuntu Focal
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED python)
  endif()
else()
find_package(Boost REQUIRED python3.8)
endif()
```

This will probably have to change for Python 3.9

I also do not know how to submit a PR and my hack is probably not the best practice nor most correct way around this.